# What is the meaning of "strike my hands together" in Ezekiel 22:13?

Tags: ezekiel, israel, niv

> Eze 22:13 I will surely strike my hands together at the unjust gain you have
>   made and at the blood you have shed in your midst.

What is the meaning of "strike my hands together"? What does God want to show Israel?

Is there any meaning about hitting hands during those times? Estimate in 500-600 BC

Answer (score 3):

It is not exactly hitting hands, but more like clapping the hands, not by the way of happiness

Rashi (Rabi Shlomo Yitzhaki): הכיתי כפי. צעקתי ווי וקינה :

Rashi says that "**strike my hands together**" is an expression of lament and grief. (Also these days, this is a common way of showing grief) There are more times which this expression appears in the Bible with this meaning:

"וַיִּחַר אַף בָּלָק אֶל בִּלְעָם **וַיִּסְפֹּק אֶת כַּפָּיו**" (numbers- (Bamidbar) 24; 10)

"וגם אני **אכה כפי אל כפי** והניחותי חמתי"  (Ezekiel 21; 22)

Comment: It is necessary to state your sources and also necessary to give the English. It is not clear to me how Ezekiel 21:22 is relevant _At his right hath been the divination -- Jerusalem, To place battering-rams, To open the mouth with slaughter, To lift up a voice with shouting, To place battering-rams against the gates, To pour out a mount, to build a fortification._ [YLT].

Comment: I'm not sure you've quoted the right source. I quoted two other sources in which a similar expression appears. (striking hands)

Comment: I am quoting the English of Ezekiel 21:22 [Young's Literal Translation]. You refer to Ezekiel 21:22 in your answer.The OP stated their question in English.

Comment: Is it possible that the Hebrew and English divsion of phrases are not the same? The original (Hebrew) Ezekiel (21:22) is what I've quoted, and you've quoted Ezekiel (21:27).

Comment: I've quoted Ezekiel 21:22 as it is known in the KJV/YLT/etc etc. The OP is Indonesian and none of their questions or answers indicate a knowledge of Hebrew. (From their profile.) You have not made clear your source or the English translation of your source.

Comment: I am not sure why I have to translate it. These verses are given in order to show this expression is common, and exists more than once.

Comment: Users need certifiable sources so that references can be checked. And users need communication in the language in which they have asked the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102309/discussion-between-efra-and-nigel-j).

Answer (score 2):

There are different translations in different Bibles. Some are phrased "strike" your hands, other "clap" your hands. Also, "strike" your "thigh", some "stomp" your "feet". So with all that movement going on, I visualize someone being seized by a fit or temper tantrum.

One might explain all of this excess movement as extremes in different emotions. First, angry at the crimes of the unrighteous that is stirring up God's wrath. Second, nervous of the possibility of needing to take up swords to cleanse and purge the land again. And also, perhaps an extreme gladness that God had pronounced judgment against those He despises.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: Thank you Julie, God bless you